# Xamarin iOS: Starting timer crashes app with no exception

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, nstimer

I'm developing a Xamarin Forms app for which I needed to write some code native, I got the code working in Android, but I can't get it to work for iOS. In Main.cs I start a scheduled timer with NSTimer which, when finished should start up the AppDelegate code for the Xamarin App.

**Main.cs:**

```
public class Application
{
    private static ISettings AppSettings => CrossSettings.Current;
    private static double startTimeMillis;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        startTimeMillis = DateTime.Now.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond;
        CheckSavedToken(args);
    }

    private static void CheckSavedToken(string[] args)
    {
        if (AppSettings.Contains(App.LoginToken))
        {
            string loginToken = AppSettings.GetValueOrDefault(App.LoginToken, string.Empty);
            if (loginToken == string.Empty)
            {
                AppSettings.Remove(App.LoginToken);
            }
        }
        double delay = 750 - (DateTime.Now.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond - startTimeMillis);
        if (delay > 0)
        {
            NSTimer.CreateScheduledTimer(delay, timer => UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate"));
        }
        else
        {
            UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate");
        }
    }
}
```

I want to check for a Login Token and stay on this screen until 750 milliseconds have passed, after that the AppDelegate can start up the Xamarin Forms part of the app.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I tried debugging with a try catch, but the app crashes without reaching the catch, I also tried using `Task.Delay()`, but that does the same thing. Even if I set the amount of time to 1, still nothing happens.

**EDIT:**

I also tried using DispatchQueue (with the same result):

```
DispatchQueue.MainQueue.DispatchAfter(new DispatchTime(DispatchTime.Now, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, (int)delay)), 
    () => UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate"));
```

I hope someone can help me with this.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why are you trying to delay the startup?

Comment: I want to have this screen visible for at least 750 milliseconds, so it won't just be a series of blinks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cause:**

The Main method is used to launch the app.

```
UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate")
```

I think your problem is caused by that you didn't even launch an application when you try to do some operations in this app.So, it get crashed with no exception.

**Solution:**

Add your delay codes in the place where you want to delay after the Main method;

You can add to `FinishedLaunching` in iOS. AppDelegate.cs:

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();


            startTimeMillis = DateTime.Now.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond;

            double delay = 750 - (DateTime.Now.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond - startTimeMillis);
            if (delay > 0)
            {
                Task.Delay(5000).Wait();

                LoadApplication(new App());

                return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);

            }
            else
            {
                LoadApplication(new App());
                return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);

            }

        }
```